# Altova MapForce adding tables from multiple Oracle database schemas

Tags: oracle, altova, map-force

How to add tables from multiple Oracle database schemas in Altova MapForce application?

I have inserted database on Mapping workspace and selected one table from schema user "AAA" which I used for connection.
When I right click on database object and select Add/Remove Tables it opens new window "Add/Remove Tables" and it is showing tables only for schema user "AAA" which I used for connection.

In that window "Add/Remove Tables" I can't find the way to select new database schema, for example to select schema user "BBB", and add table from that schema. There is some green user icon when clicked it is showing all database users but when I select one, for example "BBB" schema user, nothing happens, the window is still showing tables from schema user "AAA".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is application bug with Altova MapForce version 2012 rel. 2 sp1 (x64). With Altova MapForce version 2011, schema user can be changed in "Add/Remove Tables" window by clicking on the green user icon.